# How to calculate number of wraps and diameter of a spool wrapped in webbing, with overlap.

Tags: sequences-and-series, volume

I need to find a formula to determine the number of wraps and finished diameter of a spool, when wrapped with webbing, using overlap. My relevant parameters are:
Wt = Thickness of webbing
Ww = Width of webbing
Wo = Overlap of webbing
Wl = Length of webbing
Sd = Spool starting diameter
Sw = Spool width
I'm a bit lost as to how to get started on this, I need a formula that won't involve me needing a hundred iterations, each time a wrap changes the diameter.

Comment: What about the length of the webbing you have?

Comment: My bad, I edited to include length.

Comment: Does width go side to side, and thickness up and down?

Comment: Yes, that is correct